# Drag and drop in jAVASCRIPT not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with this drag and drop option and It's not running on mobile device anyone please help
Here is the codepen link : [https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/yLVgzMz][1]

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can use the following polyfill library in your HTML

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobile-drag-drop@2.3.0-rc.2/default.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mobile-drag-drop@2.3.0-rc.2/index.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // options are optional ;)
    MobileDragDrop.polyfill({
        // use this to make use of the scroll behaviour
        dragImageTranslateOverride: MobileDragDrop.scrollBehaviourDragImageTranslateOverride
    });
</script>
```

You can visit this link for more details: [github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop](https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop)

Answer (score 0):

poly-fill as suggested by @tony0991 is a great solution albeit it does not allow drag-n-drop on the iPad. Have you checked out this example already?
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091766/Add-support-for-standard-HTML-Drag-and-Drop-operat
There is also a codepen that does this using java
https://codepen.io/deepakkadarivel/pen/LrGEdL

```js
    window.onload = function() {
  // find the element that you want to drag.
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  
  /* listen to the touchMove event,
  every time it fires, grab the location
  of touch and assign it to box */
  
  box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    // grab the location of touch
    var touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
    
    // assign box new coordinates based on the touch.
    box.style.left = touchLocation.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = touchLocation.pageY + 'px';
  })
  
  /* record the position of the touch
  when released using touchend event.
  This will be the drop position. */
  
  box.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    // current box position.
    var x = parseInt(box.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(box.style.top);
  })
  
}
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Toggle your browser device toolbar and change device to any mobile or tablet from your browser inspect.
Credits: Deepak 
</p>
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Here Deepak (I believe that is the author's name) uses the touch move and touch end events for essentially recreating drag and drop.
I hope this helps.
Sid

Answer (score -1):

html5 drag and drop doesn't work on mobile browsers.
You can check this https://caniuse.com/?search=drag ..
Also https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp is a simple drag-n-drop example which works fine on laptop but doesn't work on mobile browsers ..

Comment: what ...?that's my question